# run several bash scripts with expect code and leave them running

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, expect

I have a bunch of several bash scripts that will perform some actions that require user input, therefore I'm using expect with it.

However, I need one to keep running. But if I use expect, the expect command will wait while the script is running and my main script will not continue.

IE:
script1 spawns a script as root:

```
#!/bin/bash
expect << EOF
spawn su root -c "/bin/bash script2.sh"
expect "Password:"
send "test\n"
set timeout -1
expect eof;
EOF
```

script2.sh will spawn a screen:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -dm nastyscript.sh
```

nastyscript.sh will spawn a binary that must keep running:

```
#!/bin/bash
expect << EOF
spawn mybinary
expect "*Enter password for my binary"
send "test\r"
expect "*I am running"
set timeout -1
expect -re . { exp_continue } eof { exit }
expect eof;
EOF
```

But, since one script is waiting for expect to finish, my main script won't continue.

Any way to do that?

Comment: Can you change script1.sh? E.g., `sudo script2.sh`

Answer (score 0):

First, you absolutely don't want to send a password with expect. Besides being very bad style it totally undermines the security of your system because you have to store a user password in cleartext. And everybody in this day and age knows by heart that you should never store any passwords in cleartext, ever.

I would recommend reading up on the manpage for `sudoers`. Then you can use sudo from within the script without having to store passwords in the clear. A more solid solution would probably be an executable with suid root. Shell scripts can't have suid for security reasons, so this would require compiling a small program.

On the other hand, if you are sure that you need multiple processes running in parallel communicating with each other, then bash version 4 offers a solution in form of the `coproc` keyword. Basically you put `coproc` in front of a command line. For simple commands it has roughly the same effect as an `&` at the end of the command line; the process will run in parallel with your script. The difference is that with `coproc` you have the `stdout` and `stdin` file descriptors of the other process available in the array `COPROC`, so your script can communicate with the other process. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html

Then you also might want to `wait` on the other process before your script exits.